# Kendo UI bind drop down value from PopupEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid which has an option to add a new record using the Popup Editor.
One field from the popup editor is a DropDownList. I have the first record from the dropdown list pre-selected when I open the Popup Editor. Since I pre-selected it, I would like it to be automatically created (bound) within the grid (when pressing "Update") **without having to manually select it again**.
[I have the example script here](https://dojo.telerik.com/@NisshinMaru/iGIDaNAR)

[image: Pre-selected dropdown value]

Comment: There is the Add New Record button in the upper left corner of the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working script:** https://dojo.telerik.com/OFinidew/28

Here's a few things that are useful to know:

## 1. Defining schemas for your dataSources

A schema is a way to define what structure to expect from your data. When a schema is defined, your data will be "bound". As much as possible you'll want to bind your data, because as a last resort you'll end up having to use templates. Normally, Kendo UI will try to figure things out and get things bound automatically, but in special cases you'll have to give it a schema. This is one of those cases.

From the code sample, it seems like the approach of the workaround was to try change the "edit" event of the kendoGrid to immediately select the "Processing" status - Instead, you can define the "Processing" status (value "2") as the defaultValue of the "status" field in your model. But then, you'll need to make sure your custom editor template CAN be bound to, which leads us to..

## 2. Using the HTML property: data-bind="value:(nameOfYourField)"

When you're making your own editor templates for the kendo popup, it has no way of knowing what part of your HTML to bind to. See the statusDropdownEditorTemplate in the link provided as an example of how this is done.

## 3. What valuePrimitive means

Normally, a kendoDropDownList will return an object containing both the Text and Value of the selected choice. But this is not what we want in this case,  because status is defined as "0", "1", "2" - so we just wanted the value. When you set valuePrimitive to true, you're instructing the kendoDropDownList to only return the value itself, not an object containing everything.

Comment: Nice answer, Ken !